# Is there a way/API that saves web page assets, that works in HTTP, not only HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, caching, browser-cache, offline-caching, offlineapps

I need to save the assets of a web page, js and css files, and the saving of the files needs to happen in HTTP context, not HTTPS. 
I need to do that, so the web page can work offline. 
Is there a JavaScript way or a JavaScript API that can help me achieve this?
Thank you!

Comment: "I  need to do that, so the web page can work offline" that has little to do with HTTP and HTTPS

Comment: Are you asking how to build a PWA with a Service Worker but using technology that doesn't demand you use HTTP?

Comment: What leads you to think for offline you require http only?  Or do you mean running your website from a local directory?

Comment: Yes Quentin, I need the same functionality as Service Worker, to save files in browser cache and make web page work offline, but I need to use it under http, not https (as Service worker require)